# \renewcommand{\section} causes unwanted bibliography header modifications

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning

So I have three files. My main .tex file, my .cls file and my .bib file. 
In my .cls file, I use these two functions:

```
\newcommand{\coloredtitle}\[2]{
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
    \node[anchor=north west, draw, rectangle, inner sep=3pt, minimum size=8mm, text height=4mm, text width=\paperwidth/2, fill=#2,#2,text=white](char){#1};

}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    {
        \Large\coloredtitle{#1}{mainblue}
    }
}
```

Then, in my .tex file, I use:

```
\section{Organismes}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

So, no problem until now... But if I insert a Bibliography, or a table of contents, here is what I get:

[image]

So, as you can see, I have my blue background, but the text is actually outside and there is this "*" inside.

The result for the table of contents is basically the same.

It seems like both the bibliography and the table of contents are somewhat considered as sections and that the \refname is not part of the title, or something.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a higher level package for redefining the format of `\section`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\colorlet{mainblue}{blue} % just for the example

\titleformat{name=\section}
 {\Large}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {\coloredtitle{mainblue}}

\newcommand{\coloredtitle}[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
    \node[
      anchor=north west,
      draw,
      rectangle,
      inner sep=3pt,
      minimum size=8mm,
      text height=4mm,
      text width=\paperwidth/2,
      fill=#1,
      #1,
      text=white
    ](char){#2};%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Organismes}

\section*{References}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the bibliography issues `\section*{References}` under the hood, but with your naïve definition, the title is taken to be `*`.

With the code above we redefine sections both numbered and unnumbered to have the same behavior.

[image]